# Understanding the proof of: set whose decimal expansion contains only $4, 7$ is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following:

> Let $E$ be the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits $4$ and $7$. Prove the every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$.

The proof that is provided to me is:

> $E$ is perfect since it is closed and its every point is a limit point of $E$. We have already shown that $E$ is closed. Now, let $p \in E$ where $p = 0.p_1p_2 \dots p_n \dots$. It suffices to show that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. To this end, let $r > 0$. Then, $\exists N$ such that $\frac{3}{10^N} < r$. Let $p' = 0.p_1p_2 \dots p_n s_{n+1}\dots$ where $s_{n+1} = 4$ if $p_{n+1} = 7$ and $s_{n+1} = 7$ if $p_{n+1} = 4$. Then, $p' \in N_r(p), p' \in E,$ and $p' \ne p$. Since $r > 0$ was arbitrary, $p$ is a limit point of $E$.

Can someone please explain why "$\exists N$ such that $\frac{3}{10^N} < r$" and why "$p' \in N_r(p)$"?

Comment: Can you write out your thinking process and where you are stuck? Your block is more of a logical-reasoning block, and so stating your though process would greatly help. This is a pretty standard proof, and explaining those statements essentially amount to restating them.  IE The explanations are: "For a fixed $r$, clearly for some large enough $N$, we have $ \frac{3}{10^N} < r$" and "Clearly by the definition, ($ |p - p'| < r$ so) $ p' \in N_r (p)$".

Comment: @CalvinLin As far as I understand, it is that $r > 0$. I wanted to ask why we chose $\frac{3}{10^N}$ and not say $\frac{1}{10^N}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Also, the fact that "the definition" holds is precisely what the proof is trying to establish. So, we can't just use the definition and say that it holds. :)

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Calvin is referring to the definition of $p'$, which indeed ensures that $|p-p'|<r$ and hence by definition of $N_r(p)$ that $p'\in N_r(p)$. This in no way assumes what we’re trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll take your questions in reverse order. First, $p'\in N_r(p)$ because it was constructed to ensure that this is the case. Specifically, the decimal expansions of $p$ and $p'$ both begin $0.p_1p_2\ldots p_n$, where $n$ is large enough that $\frac3{10^n}<r$. The next digit of the expansion of $p$ is $p_{n+1}$, and the next digit of the expansion of $p'$ is $7$ if $p_{n+1}=4$ and $4$ if $p_{n+1}=7$. Thus, the largest possible value for $|p-p'|$ is

$$0.\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_n3333\ldots<\frac1{10^n}\cdot\frac13<\frac3{10^n}<r\;.$$

Thus, $|p-p'|<r$, and that by definition (of $N_r(p)$) means that $p'\in N_r(p)$.

I suspect that the choice of $n$ such that $\frac3{10^n}<r$ embodies a typo, and that the author intended to choose $n$ large enough that $\frac1{3\cdot10^n}<r$, since, as I pointed out above, $\frac1{3\cdot10^n}$ is the largest possible value of $|p-p'|$ when $p'$ is constructed according to the recipe actually used.

Comment: Pardon me if this is far too elementary, but isn't it the case that both $\frac{3}{10^n}$ and $\frac{1}{3 \cdot 10^n}$ act as lower bounds for $r$ (as you show in the displayed equation in your answer) and thus, it is valid to take  $\frac{3}{10^n}  < r$ as well in place of $\frac{1}{3 \cdot 10^n} < r$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: Yes, both work, but there’s no obvious reason to pick $\frac3{10^n}$, and since you asked about it, I wanted at least to try to figure out why on earth the author had used it.